# How can I inject a large html code onclick of a button using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to generate a form onclick of a button and submit the same using Javascript.

How can I add a large html code without manually creating DOM elements and appending it?

Is there any way so that whole html code can get append at once?

Comment: You could put it in a file and open it/append it using js.

Comment: *cough* `insertAdjacentHTML`. But you still make the browser use a parser for it.

Comment: `document.getElementById('insertion_point').innerHTML  = 'long block of html'`

Comment: @MarcB , if  I had to save the data of the form in the same js file , how can I achieve the same ? Would the id of the elements inside the form work in the js file as well ?

Comment: jquery would make it pretty easy. you could have something like `...innerHTML = $('#yourform').serialize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="form-container"> </div>  
<button id ="get-form" onclick="getForm()">Get Form</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
  <script>
   var form = '<form>
                    <h1>form title</h1>
                    </form>';
    function() {
      document.getElementById('form-container').innerHTML = form;
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-container"> </div>  
<button id ="get-form"></button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#get-form').click(function(){
        $( ".form-container").load( "ajax/form.html" );
    });
```

**form.html**

```
<form>
<h1>form title</h1>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Could you please share , how can I save the data of the form to the same js file ?